# Split physicsBody or alternatives

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, alpha-transparency, skphysicsbody

I have a picture set up in spritekit that takes up the whole screen, which has its own physicsBody as follows:

[image: original]

I set up the touch methods so that the user "draws" on the screen with a clear color, essentially removing alpha from the picture:

[image: drawing with clear color]

As you can see, my physicsBody changes as the alpha values in the image change. Now, as I keep drawing closer and closer to another edge, the physicsBody acts the way it should, keeping everything that isnt alpha 0 part of the body:

[image: another picture]

However, when the texture is eventually split by a line with alpha value of 0, the physics body discludes one of the portions:

[image: final alpha picture]

This is undesired behavior, as I would like to keep EVERYTHING that has an alpha value over 0 part of the body. I trie splitting the body into multiple parts, essentially meaning that if a line is drawn between them, there will be two bodies. However, this still doesn't change anything if a line is drawn within one of the bodies.

Does anyone know how I can split the bodies if they are separated? Maybe other alternatives to accomplish the same task? Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the physics body is being used for here. To me this looks like a static node, so why use a `physicsBody`? I'm going to assume you are making a "create your own character" editor for a game. Also, you need to realise that precise physics bodies are extremely computationally expensive to use. Physics bodies (aka hitboxes) should always be approximations, like using a circle for a pentagonal-shaped object (you approximate the flat edges).

Comment: This is a simplified example of a much more complex game situation. I used a random picture for simulation purposes, whereas the physicsBody in the actual game represents a much bigger purpose. I understand the computational expense for a physicsBody as so, but you have to understand that it is required in my game.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Code of what? I don't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just have an `SKNode` to represent the whole thing, then add a child `SKNode` with a `physicsBody` attached. Then, when you detect that the user has "split" the body in half, reduce the existing child node's `physicsBody` where the split happens, and add a new child node with the rest of the split entity as its `physicsBody`. If you split it multiple times you'll eventually have multiple nodes, each with its own `physicsBody`, linked together (related) by the parent `SKNode`.

You can do it this way (one node with heaps of children), or create a tree structure where every split will further split each child's `physicsBody` into two children, so every node will have at most two children. This will create a binary search tree which you can use for collisions if you wish.

Comment: Code exemple for the one node, heaps of children method?

Comment: I dont know how i would split the node at the location where split happens

Comment: I think that this is beyond the scope of this question. You could detect if the x-length of a blanked out area is equal to or greater than the width of your physics body. There are heaps of different ways you might be able to do it, but without knowing your code or the way you plan to do the "blanking out" it's difficult to make a suggestion.

Comment: For the one node, heaps of children method, I can't give you example code beyond running a detection function, and if it returns true then create a new node and use `parent.addChild()` to add that node to the whole picture. I can't do your work for you, I can only suggest a method you could use. It is really up to you to take that method and turn it into code yourself.

Comment: I clearly explained I have already run a detection method by using multiple nodes, and it was no efficient enough. Im not asking for you to do the work for me - ed ist., the length doesnt have to be greater than or equal to the width of the screen. That is in no way relavent or working. Please refrain from speaking if you will criticize a perfectly valid question.

Comment: And there's not much code involved. I said its a physicsBody made with the alphaThreshold method. That's one line of code that is not worth mentioning, for if you knew what that was, you wouldn't criticize the question.

Comment: Please tell me where you said "I have come up with a detection algorithm" and I will gladly apologise. Reading through everything you've said, you have only asked how to do it, not that you have already done it. I was not criticising anything, I think you are misunderstanding me. I'm saying that I can describe a method, but you need to decide how you will implement it, I can't really do that for you. You never said anything about using `alphaThreshold` neither. You are telling me that you have informed me of things when you actually haven't.

Comment: Besides, you are asking a second question, and it should be asked separately to this one. I have given you a perfectly valid answer to your ORIGINAL QUESTION. You did not specify that you actually needed code, just that you needed a "way" to do it, as well. Please don't get frustrated for no reason because that will not get you any help at all.

Comment: "I trie splitting the body into multiple parts, essentially meaning that if a line is drawn between them, there will be two bodies. However, this still doesn't change anything if a line is drawn within one of the bodies."

Comment: Sorry if I'm getting frustrated. I just found it disrespectful that you said you won't implement it for me. As I have attempted to say, I have tried splitting the nodes/physics bodies every time a line is drawn. This keeps adding on, however, as I was "guessing" where the line may be drawn (essentially splitting the body before the line is drawn). I use CGImageContext to draw with an alpha of 0, basically de-alpha'ing the image (with the physics body changing to include only alpha>0). My question isn't really beyond the scope of anything. Sure I can spplit the body, but how at that exact point

Comment: This IS beyond the scope of this question. And it is not disrespectful for me to answer your request of, "Code it for me," with, "No," as I don't work for you and can do as I please. To do what you're saying, you could have to have an algorithm detect points along the drawn line and connect them together to form a path. You can then use the point locations along the path to detect exactly where the drawn parts are. You may even need to use some AI to check if two pieces are still connected at any point. This is COMPLICATED, and beyond the scope of this question. Ask another separate question.

Comment: Where did i say code it for me? I said provide an example. A method, a function, whatever it may be. Do you think I not know how to add a child to a node? My question IS COMPLICATED. This IS the question I am asking, and your answer is too simple. We can keep arguing, or you can post an answer to a legitamate issue I am having

Comment: Without disrespect, I can tell myself what to do, but I need to know HOW. Yeah, I need to split the body into two whereever the 'cut' was made. My original post didnt say "tell me what to do", it asked whether you knew HOW to do it

Comment: "Code exemple for the one node, heaps of children method?" This involves everything you have just said. I've also just told you a way of detecting where the split happens. I'm done.

Comment: Tell me the name of the method, dont describe it. Link me to some other answer, give me a google page. You CANT; because your answer is incomplete. If im asking how to split an orange after you cut it, dont tell me to separate it at the point it was cut. Thats a fallacy of missing the point - be precise, this is Stack Overflow

Comment: So getting the location of where the split happens does not give you the location of where the split happens? If I cut an orange and then tell you "You can tell where to split it because this bit here has been cut and looks like a good place to split it" then I would say that is a satisfactory answer to the question.

Comment: How does location help me split the two, is what i'm asking?

Comment: That is where I believe you are missing the point. I have the location of every drawn clear point, finding one of those wouldnt be a problem. Finding where two points intersect is inefficient, as it is a thousand times more likely for it to intersect with something like the previous location. I would like to know not this, but my OP - how the heck do I split the bodies. h o w

Comment: If you have the location you then know where to place an edge. Place the edge as part of a `CGPath` that you will then use to form the `physicsBody`. That's the easy part. Forming the edge is the hard part.

Comment: The edge is already a CGPath, so it wouldn't matter (the whole physics body is defined by a CGPath, basically). How can I split one node into two? Define two physics bodies based off of one?

Comment: Again, use the locations to form an edge. Make two physicsBodies that incorporate that new edge as well as the rest of their respective edges. You have two physicsBodies now.